# the data has 101 values why result has 303 values?

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap

Data here is "sales" data with two columns price and sales and 16 rows
for eg,

```
price sales
49    81996
46    91735
50    70830
45    101192
51    78319
47    105369
47    68564
46    95523
49    88834
46    89511
45    107836
52    81410
50    67817
54    59207
50    83310
46    71431
```

in the code below, Using “dim(my.boot.price)” it can be shown that we have 101 values in the input data 
But
Results
Shows us we have 303 rows. Why? Please correct the script attached.

```
#=== bootstrapping prediction price range
library(boot)

# bootstrap function 
my.boot <- function(formula, data, indices, price) {
  d <- data[indices,] 
  fit <- lm(formula, data=d)

  my.new.data<-data.frame(price)
  pred_interval <- predict(fit, newdata=my.new.data, interval="prediction",
                           level = 0.95)
  colnames(pred_interval)[2:3]<-c("pred.lwr","pred.upr")
  # return the prediction 
  return(pred_interval)
} 

###############################################
# run the bootstrap 
# determine the single value to bootstrap
my.boot.price=data.frame(price=seq(45,55,.1))
dim(my.boot.price)
results <- boot(data=sales, statistic=my.boot, 
                R=2000, formula=sales~price, price=my.boot.price)

# view results
results
```

Comment: Pls update the question with `dput(sales)`

Comment: The first argument of the `my.boot` function must be the data, the 2nd is `indices`, only then come the other arguments.

Comment: The function returns **3** values, the predicted point, the lower and the upper CI limits. And **3*101** == what you have.